# how could i get all user role list in edit page in my custom module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, user-roles

I want to show user role list in my custom module edit page my code is as below

```
$fieldset->addField(
       'admin_role_ids',
       'multiselect',
       [
         'name'     => 'permission[admin_role_ids]',
         'label'    => __('Allowed for Roles'),
         'title'    => __('Allowed for Roles'),
         'values'   => $this->_adminSession->getUser()->getRole(),
       ]
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) You can use class `\Magento\Authorization\Model\ResourceModel\Role\Grid\Collection` to get admin roles:**

```
protected $roleCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Authorization\Model\ResourceModel\Role\Grid\CollectionFactory $roleCollectionFactory,
) {
  $this->roleCollectionFactory = $roleCollectionFactory;
}

public function getRoles()
{
    $role = $this->roleCollectionFactory->create();
    print_r($role->getData());
}
```

**2) Use class `Magento\Authorization\Model\ResourceModel\Role\Collection` to get admin role with all admin user:**

```
protected $roleCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Authorization\Model\ResourceModel\Role\CollectionFactory $roleCollectionFactory,
) {
  $this->roleCollectionFactory = $roleCollectionFactory;
}

public function getRoles()
{
    $role = $this->roleCollectionFactory->create();
    print_r($role->getData());
}
```